# Does Airflow restart affect current running jobs?

Tags: airflow

This seems like a mundane question but just to be on the safe side,
what are the effects of restarting the airflow service on the jobs which are currently running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only restart the airflow webserver/scheduler processes then the running jobs are not affected. However restarting the worker process kills the job (killed as zombie - http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#zombies-undeads) and then it may or may not be retried accordingly to the dag/task rules.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful insight :)

Comment: this is actually not true for LocalExecuter, in which case, restarting the scheduler will send SIGTERM to all running tasks

Comment: Is there any way to keep existing jobs running after a scheduler restart? (with local executor)